# java if statement test output error

Tags: java

I have a small java project thats connected to a database back-end. I have a login function but when I put it in my test Harness I can't get it to give me the correct output back there.

```
public boolean validateLogin(User validate) {
        {
            Connection conn = null;

            String dbUserName = "root"; // MySQL database username
            String dbPassword = "nbuser"; // MySQL database password


            boolean returnValue = false;

            String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";

            try {
                Class forNam = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                try {

                    forNam.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            }

            try {

                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUserName, dbPassword);
                System.out.println("Database connection establish...!");

                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login_register WHERE user_id='" + validate.getUserID() + "'");
                if (rs.next()) {
                    if (rs.getString(2).equals(validate.getUserPassword())) {
                        System.out.println("User and Password Match");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No User Or Password Match");
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("No User Or Password Match");
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Cannot connect to database server...!!");

            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {

                        conn.close();
                        System.out.println("Database connection terminated...!!!");
                        returnValue = true;
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnValue;

        }
    }
```

Now my test code to see if this statement works

```
User testLogin = new User();
testLogin.setUserID("userid");
testLogin.setUserPassword("password");
 if (test.validateLogin(testLogin)) {
    System.out.println("User logged in");
} 
 else {
    System.out.println("Failed to login");
}
```

the two bits of information above are in my database so my output in my IDE is as follows:

```
Database connection establish...!
User and Password Match
Database connection terminated...!!!
User logged in
```

but If I change the values to something not in the database I get

```
Database connection establish...!
No User Or Password Match
Database connection terminated...!!!
User logged in
```

so the issue is in my test code when the values don't match I can't get it to say they dont match, which I need for a function later on in my work.
Any ideas what I need to change on my test code to get to to say `"failed to login"` if the id and password don't match on my test side

Comment: Your method always return true. Well, practically almost always. Cause you set return value to `true` in finally clause. What did you expect?

Comment: Hiding exceptions (catching them and not handling them) is always a bad idea. At the very, very minimum log them. If you do not know what to do with that exception, rethrow it.

Comment: Personally I'd do some work on the login code first. Maybe start over, build up functionality a piece at a time, and test as you go. That code is... Well, it needs work.

Comment: Let me just say that your code is **highly** vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use 'prepared statements' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to avoid this.

Comment: Also, You're not closing the `Statement` and the `ResultSet` objects. That may cause memory leak at a certain time.

Comment: And plain text passwords in the database, sql injection, your users won't be very happy :)

Comment: my project is a proof of concept, and this is just a login for the front end of my project to be demonstrated between a few tutors

Comment: Those few tutors will be disappointed. The tasks you get mimic the issues found in the real world. If your presented solution fails at one of the most important aspects of a real world project that needs special care and attention, even though your solution might be working (under some circumstances... but that is a story of its own), your tutors will be less than happy about it. Believe me. I've been on duty for accepting homeworks quite some time. These kinds of works were where I got picky about things...

Comment: Not only the tutors, but the students. There's almost nothing right about this example, yet it's simple enough that it could be turned in to a great example without much effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (rs.getString(2).equals(validate.getUserPassword())) {
        System.out.println("User and Password Match");
        returnValue =true;
                    } else {
        System.out.println("No User Or Password Match");
         returnValue =false;
                    }
```

and remove `returnValue =true;` from finally block

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your method:

1. You should place your code in one single try/catch block. The way you place it, if the code `Class forNam = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` in the first try block fails, the second one would still be executed, which would lead to exceptions arising from the connection not being able to be opened.
2. Your finally() block makes sure the method always returns true. You should place the `returnValue = true;` piece inside the `if (rs.getString(2).equals(validate.getUserPassword())) {` block, together with the "User and Password Match" scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is one part you have trouble with:

```
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {

                    conn.close();
                    System.out.println("Database connection terminated...!!!");
                    //delete the next line:
                    //returnValue = true; // <-- in a finally block, this will always run...
```

Also, I noticed, you don't set returnValue to true when it should be done:

```
            if (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString(2).equals(validate.getUserPassword())) {
                    System.out.println("User and Password Match");
                    //add this line:                         
                    returnValue=true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No User Or Password Match");
                }
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("No User Or Password Match");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The success state is not depend on "can I connect to the database" but should be set if the passwords do match...

```
            if (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString(2).equals(validate.getUserPassword())) {
                    System.out.println("User and Password Match");
                    returnValue = true; // <---
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No User Or Password Match");
                }
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("No User Or Password Match");
            }
```

Do NOT set the value to true in the `finally` clause.

Comment: And: Do not transfer passwords in plain text.